# how to get single script variable data from multiple script in html page

Tags: javascript, python-2.7, xpath, scrapy

I have one html page there where several script tag but i want only one varible data from within those script .
you can find html page code here

https://jsfiddle.net/9Lzc5fxy/

i only want data of **var roomsAndRatePlans** variable because but when i execute below code i get all data within that script tag can any one help me to fix that

Here i code i used to retrieve that data.

```
f = codecs.open("response.html", 'r')

samplenew = f.read()

selector = scrapy.Selector(text=samplenew, type='html')
snippet = selector.css('script:contains("roomsAndRatesData")::text').get()

jstree = js2xml.parse(snippet)

Data = js2xml.pretty_print(jstree)
```

But i always get all data from script tag that contain that variable and because of that i alway get convertion error in

jstree = js2xml.parse(snippet)

Can any one suggest any solution so i can retrieve only that variable data **"var roomsAndRatePlans"**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always use regular expressions for the cases when I need to retrieve some variable from JS code.

You can achieve what you want with `re_first` method:

```
import json

data_str = (selector
    .css('script:contains("roomsAndRatesData")::text')
    .re_first(r'var roomsAndRatePlans = (\{.*\}),'
)
data = json.loads(data_str)
```

The object in `data` will look like this:

```
{
    'propertyData': {
        'bookingFeeMessageEnabled': True,
        'breakfastChargeAvailable': True,
        'breakfastIncludedAtProperty': False
    },
    'rooms': {
        '24-285501': {
            'locale': 'en',
            'providerId': '24',
            'roomTypeCode': '285501'
        }
    }
}
```

P.S. If you use `scrapy` only for its `Selector` functionality, you can use `parsel` instead, which is a `scrapy` dependency.